# Ruby on Rails process data after session was finished.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to process large files uploaded by user. Process takes around 5 hours. What is the best way to process data after user finished a session and log out so it does not need to stay connected to the server for 5 hours. Is any gems which can do that?. Or I have to use call-backs or hooks? I just can not find right way of doing it.

Comment: Have a look at sidekiq. http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into background processing. [This](http://www.sitepoint.com/comparing-ruby-background-processing-libraries-delayed-job/) is a great article to get started: It explains the basic ideas and shows the three most commonly used options in rails.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to, I'd suggest using Active Job, use it with something like sidekiq or Resque

Take a look at http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

Obviously only available in rails 4.2 and above, but definitely worth the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use rails 4.2, do so.  The ActiveJob functionality will do what you want.

I created a simple batch system years ago to process files in conjunction with rails apps.  I work with large music catalogs and have people uploading wav and aif files that need to be processed in various ways.  My rails app receives the file and stores the input file using carrierwave.  That creates a batch item which is tied to a batch_item_type that has a reference to a script file to process the input file.  I then have a piece of code that runs every few minutes and processes whatever is in the queue, of course using locking to make sure it only can run one at a time.

For 5 hour jobs you might look at using Amazon EC2 for on-demand processing.